# How do I find an XML element by attribute using LINQ to XML?

Tags: .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm learning LINQ to XML and need to find the existence of an element with a particular attribute. At the moment I'm using:

```
XElement groupCollectionXml = XElement.Parse(groupCollection.Xml);
IEnumerable<XElement> groupFind =
    from vw in groupCollectionXml.Elements("Group")
    where (string) vw.Attribute("Name") == groupName
    select vw;

if (groupFind.Count() == 0)
    return false;
else
    return true;
```

I know there is a more concise way of doing this, probably using Any(), but I'm not sure how to rewrite the query to use it. Does anyone have some good advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the other two answers. I combined the conciseness of one with the correctness of another, then stirred and came up with this which works well:

```
groupCollectionXml.Elements("Group").Any(
  vw => string.Equals(vw.Attribute("Name").Value, groupName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
groupCollectionXml.Elements("Group").Any(
    vw=>(string)vw.Attribute("Name") == groupName
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
groupCollectionXml.
    Elements("Group").
    Where(item=>String.
        Equals(item.Attribute("Name"), groupName, OrdinalIgnoreCase)).
    Any();
```

if you want it all on one line

Comment: Could you please give another answer where it's not all on one line and is easier to read?